# Fast, Fast random integer generator

Tags: c++, random

There are multiple algorithms out there like XorShift that are really fast generating random numbers which satisfy general use. Unfortunately, I need to generate a **random integer from [0 to 10]** and using the `rand()` function in my code results in a slowdown of ~23%.

**Question:** What is the fastest way to generate an integer from [0 to 10]?

Edit: Information based on Brandon's comment:

*Slowdown of ~23% assumes you have compared it to something. What did you compare it to?*

*> I'm doing rand() % 10 > 5.*

Also:

- Using `srand(time(0));` outside the loop is doing nothing.
- `rand() % 10` isolated is ~19%, so comparing is not affecting the performance that much.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, integer?

Comment: Slowdown of ~23% assumes you have compared it to something.  What did you compare it to?

Comment: Does your question really essentially boil down to *"I get a random value between 0 and 2^32-1 and I have no clue how to bring that back to 0 to 10"*? Did you consider `int myRand =  xorshift() % 11;`?

Comment: The wikipedia link that @ColonelThirtyTwo gave you contains links to a whole bunch of pseudo-random algorithms, probably most of them are for generating integers. I've implemented my own  [Linear Conguential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) based on that page when I needed something quick and didn't care too much about the quality.

Comment: [Obligatory](http://etoan.com/random-number-generation/dilbert2001182781025.gif).

Comment: @Niels Hopefully he hasn't, because that's an awfully broken solution. Which brings me to the next point: Don't implement random generators yourself, you'll probably subtly break it.

Comment: @Voo the fact that it has a 1 in 390 million skew towards `[0-3]` doesn't make it *awfully broken* imho unless you're running a big money lottery. For most applications, especially if speed is 'vital' unlike with a lottery, it's fine to have such a minor statistical anomaly. It wasn't really my point though that it would be the ultimate solution, more about discovering the real question being asked.

Comment: @Brandon, You are reading my code! :) I did rand() % 10 > 5.

Comment: @Niels As a prof of mine used to say: If I don't have to make it correct, I can make it arbitrarily fast. That said, yes this can be perfectly fine, but one should clearly state the limitations, because in the end - if you start accepting inaccuracies `return 4` is going to be way faster and still accurate ~9% of the time ;-)

Comment: @Voo fair point  :P  I would still prefer the term *slightly incorrect* over *awfully broken* for an anomaly this small  ;)

Comment: @Niels Fair point ;) Poetic license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xorshift is a great algorithm. Use it to generate a buffer full of random bits. Just because it fills the buffer 32 bits at a time is no reason you have to read them out of the buffer 32 bits at a time. And since you want speed, you want to avoid division (and mod). The only way to do that is by rejection sampling (also the only way to get perfectly unbiased numbers).

Since you only need 11 values (0 to 10), you only need 4 bits per sample. You'll reject 5 out of every 16, but since you'll have 8 samples per 32 bits, that leaves you an average of 5.5 output values for each iteration of the Xorshift.

So, fill a big buffer from Xorshift, then convert that buffer into (0 to 10) values with something like this:

```
for (int b = 0; b < sizeof inbuf; b += 1) {
    uint8_t v = ((uint8_t *)inbuf)[b];

    if ((v & 0x0F) < 10) { *outbuf++ = v & 0x0F; }
    if (((v >> 4) & 0x0F) < 10) { *outbuf++ = ((v >> 4) & 0x0F; }
}
```

Make `outbuf` a byte array twice the size as `inbuf`, and it'll be about 11/16 full. Refill both buffers as needed.

Comment: So, in a nutshell: the slowdown is because I'm dividing by huge number.

Comment: What huge number? You're probably dividing by 11 for each number you need, and that's certainly not necessary, and you're probably using more random bits than you need. Or something else entirely might be your slow point. No way for me to know.

Comment: I mean I'm generating a big random number that is not needed. And reducing that long random number to the required range is causing the bottleneck. Generating the number is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's one possible bottleneck, that's why I suggest getting 5.5 numbers per round of Xorshift rather than just one. But again, I can't guarantee that's your bottleneck, only a profiler can tell that.

Comment: You can gain better efficiency by taking two samples from every 7 bits (rejecting 7 out of 128), but I doubt it's worth the extra complexity.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the standard mersenne twister implementation? The following example is from Microsoft's online help:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    random_device rd;   // non-deterministic generator
    mt19937 gen(rd());  // to seed mersenne twister.
    uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0,10); // distribute results between 1 and 10 inclusive.

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cout << dist(gen) << " "; // pass the generator to the distribution.
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Last time I used the implementation from [Makoto Matsumoto](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) and it was way faster than `rand()`. I have not benchmarked it, but I would guess that the standard implementation is also faster.

SSE2 also has special support for random number generation which may be even faster: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-random-number-generator-on-the-intel-pentiumr-4-processor

Comment: MT is deadly slow, and less accurate than Xorshift he already knows about.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I'm not an expert an random number generators, but at least the paper "SIMD-oriented fast MT" shows some benchmarks which seems to indicate that MT is at least as fast as xorshift (http://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/0/6d1037a177434162c125756c0036327a/$FILE/sfmt.pdf, tables 1 and 2  on page 11). It may be biased, though.

Comment: Might be on some machines I suppose. Or maybe my code could use some optimzation....

Comment: why MT is in standard library? on my machine is twice slow and SIMD enabled